# Foreach in Linq

Tags: linq

Can I replace these foreach's with LINQ or delegates?

```
    foreach (List<Shopping.BasketPayment> payList in Basket.basketPayments)
    { 
        foreach (var pay in payList)
        {
            if (pay.paymentMethod == "Money Order" 
            {
                foreach (OrderItem orderItem in order.Items)
                {
```

Comment: basketPayments contains List<Shopping.BasketPayment> items, List<Shopping.BasketPayment> contains pay T (whatever type be) items,
but where does order come from?

Comment: you can flatten a list via SelectMany() calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var qry = from payList in Basket.basketPayments
          from pay in payList
          where pay.paymentMethod == "Money Order"
          from orderItem in order.Items // where did "order" come from?
          ... etc ending in `select` of one or more articles

foreach(var item in qry) {
    // do something with item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var allPayments = Basket.basketPayments.SelectMany(p => p);
var moneyOrders = allPayments.Where(p => p.paymentMethod == "Money Order");

foreach(var payment in moneyOrders)
{
    foreach(OrderItem item in order.Items)
    {

    }
}
```